# Preserve a custom number format without having applied it

Tags: excel, formatting

I have observed that if I click on cell *->Manage cell formats->CustomFormats->Add New format* the new format is saved, but if I reformat the cell with a standard text format, the previous custom format is deleted from Excel.

Can I add a custom number format in Excel and retain it without applying it immediately to any cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the format to a cell in a hidden sheet.

Answer (score 0):

From [Create a custom number format](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?CorrelationId=36e1b372-c6c5-4663-bdd4-c335637c2c2f&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US):

> A custom number format is stored in the workbook in which it was created and will not be available in any other workbooks. To use a custom format in a new workbook, you can save the current workbook as an Excel template that you can use as the basis for the new workbook.